# Copy data from one cell to another - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

So, I've been googling for a while now and can't seem to find the answer:

What I want is a query for copying data from one cell to another of the same table, something like:

```
COPY column1 FROM mytable WHERE id=1 TO WHERE id=5
```

So now I would have the same data in column1 on id 1 and id 5

PS: If there is a solution on phpmyadmin that'd be amazing too, I can work with anything

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like this

```
update mytable set column1 = (select column1 from (select column1 from mytable where id = 2) as alias) where id = 5;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @martingoldthen you might want to accept this as the correct answer then.

Comment: @LajosArpad Sorry, I'm new to all this. Done!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1 INTO @column1_Value FROM mytable where id = 2;

update mytable set column1= @column1_Value where id = 5;
```